# indicator-cpufreq unable to choose powersave

Tags: lubuntu, power-management, cpu, intel-cpu

I'm on `Lenovo G50` laptop, `Lubuntu 22.04`. I installed `indicator-cpufreq`.
When I run it (I'm using `i3`) I'm unable to switch it to `powersave`.
It always switches back to `performance`.
Can I fix it?